# PhpStorm how to add hotkey to Database tool, as you can see others have but database doesn't

Tags: phpstorm, shortcut, jetbrains-ide, hotkeys

[image]

> PhpStorm how to add hotkey to Database tool, as you can see others have but database doesn't

Answer (score 3):

Open the **Settings / Preferences** dialog by pressing `⌘,` or by choosing `File | Settings` for Windows and Linux or `IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences` for macOS, and click `Keymap`.

Then under the `Tool Windows` item you can change the hotkey. See also the screenshot below.

Source: [IntelliJ IDEA - Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)

[image]